# Repeating values caught with a binary classifier

Tags: data, bigdata, variance, binary-classification

If my machine is broken, it starts to repeat certain channels. Thing is if there are no out-liars, it is difficult to tell it's broken as we would expect all data points to be around the same value. I have 10 parameters that usually tell me the same info. Each of those parameters come from the same source which is a waveform. I want to analyze the waveform but it has 4000 data points for each channel. The 10 parameters are a summary statistic of this waveform

No luck predicting whether a machine is broken or not using a Keras binary Classifier.
My models so far work well when the data has repeated extreme values across the channels, in any of the 10 parameter. When it comes to data that looks flat across the channels, it doesn't detect it.

If I want to train my model with the waveform, it will be 1 million data points long for every training point. Which is unreasonable. Furthermore I don't know what other characteristics of a wave to use to summarize the wave.

**What classifiers are more focused on detecting possible repeated values? Like 50 channels repeat 50 channels but still with natural variations.
Should I even try the waveform? Maybe compare pictures of the waves?
Maybe I just need to analyze the variation of repeated channels compared to non-repeated channels?
(Which I have tried but repeated channels are only repeated once if it's a bad machine, so I'm unsure of how to approach it well)**

Any ideas/brainstorming/questions are greatly appreciated. Also I am a lone DS don't really have many people to work with.